# connection refuse error while using soapui

Tags: soapui

When I have tried to call soap API via soapui (http://localhost:8080) I have got "connection refuse error".Can anyone please help me.

Comment: Are you hosting anything on localhost:8080? "Connection refused" is a sign that you aren't.

Comment: please be more specific, that question can have a lot of answers dependent on what you are doing besides.

Comment: I have put my project into the xampp. After that, I have imported wsdl file. But when I want to run the xml file I have got this error